# Test vector length (JS) for use with conditional panel (Shiny R)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to create a conditional panel in Shiny based on the length of an input (character string) vector. Specifically, I have a fileInput widget (e.g. Id = `FILEWIDGET`), and I want to render a conditional panel only if the number of uploaded files is <= 1. I don't speak javascript, but the conditional written in R would look like:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = input$FILEWIDGET$name <= 1 , ...)
```

Hopefully this is a straightforward question for those familiar with JS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an expression to put in the conditionalPanel to make it work.

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("files","sdfsd", multiple = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel("$('#files')[0].files.length <= 1", p("<= 1 files selected"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
))
```

However, it's a little awkward because it doesn't use the usual shiny condition format of "input.files...", and instead I'm using jQuery for the condition.  I don't know if the Shiny devs will say this is fine or if they'll say it's bad.  Files are handled in a weird way in Shiny and using `input.files.files.length` doesn't seem to work, that's why I had to revert to jQuery